# Return user input into an undefined array?

Tags: c#, arrays

I am a student working on a homework assignment for school. My problem is that I am trying to gather a number of user inputs based on the length of one array, and return those inputs into a new array of the same length. The second array can't be hard coded, because it has to be dynamic and change based on how many user inputs there were in the first array. Here is my code.

```
public static decimal[] PromptForDecimals(string[] array1)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < array1.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("");
        string inputString = Console.ReadLine();
        decimal input;
        while (!decimal.TryParse(inputString, out input))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number value.");
            inputString = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        decimal[] inputArray;
        inputArray[i] = input;

        return inputArray;
```

Basically, I'm trying to create an array of `decimal` values to correspond to the string values of `array1`. The problem is I can't add values into an undefined array because they are outside of the range. I have tried using an `ArrayList` for `inputArray`, but I get an invalid cast error.

Anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static decimal[] PromptForDecimals(string[] array1)
    {
        decimal[] inputArray = new decimal[array1.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < array1.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("");
            string inputString = Console.ReadLine();

            decimal input;
            while (!decimal.TryParse(inputString, out input))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number value.");
                inputString = Console.ReadLine();
            }

            inputArray[i] = input;

            return inputArray;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this. I hope it will work for you.

```
public static decimal[] PromptForDecimals(string[] array1)
{
    decimal[] inputArray = new decimal[array1.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < array1.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("");
        string inputString = Console.ReadLine();

        decimal input;
        while (!decimal.TryParse(inputString, out input))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number value.");
            inputString = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        inputArray[i] = input;                
    }

    return inputArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should probably put the `return` statement and the declaration of the `inputArray` outside the for loop.

Second, to create your `inputArray`, you just need to create an array that has a length of `inputArray.Length`!

```
// remember to put this before the for loop.
decimal[] inputArray = new decimal[inputArray.Length];
```

In the for loop, you can then write:

```
// don't redeclare inputArray again!
inputArray[i] = input;
```

After the for loop, return `inputArray`:

```
return inputArray;
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the solution.

1) With the statement `decimal[] inputArray` you have only declared an array, but not created one.

2) You must create it before you enter the loop

3) As shown below, when creating the array, you can give it the same number of elements as `inputArray`

```
public static decimal[] PromptForDecimals( string[] array1 )
{
    decimal[] inputArray = new decimal[array1.Length];
    for( int i = 0; i < array1.Length; i++ )
    {
        Console.WriteLine( "" );
        string inputString = Console.ReadLine();

        decimal input;
        while( !decimal.TryParse( inputString, out input ) )
        {
            Console.WriteLine( "Please enter a number value." );
            inputString = Console.ReadLine();
        }
        inputArray[i] = input;
    }

    return inputArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your life easier and use LINQ. All of the creating of arrays and making sure that you're using the right indices are done for you.

```
public static decimal[] PromptForDecimals(string[] array1)
{
    return
        array1
            .Select(x =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(x);
                string inputString = Console.ReadLine();
                decimal input;
                while (!decimal.TryParse(inputString, out input))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number value.");
                    inputString = Console.ReadLine();
                }
                return input;
            })
            .ToArray();
}
```